# Loading html into div via jquery disables scripts on that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can load html into divs via jquery successfully , but when i cant apply scripts to that div. I searched throughout stack overflow , google , tried various things like getting script on load etc.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=''>
    <head>
       <meta charset='utf-8'>  
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarai_nustat.css"> 
       <title>Pasauliniai karai</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){     // Loading here
                 $("#cssmenu").load("meniu.html");
                 $(".sidebar1").load("sidebar1.html");
                 $(".sidebar2").load("sidebar2.html");           
            });
        </script>
       </head>

    <body>

      <div class = "visa_puslapio_info ">
        <div id="cssmenu"></div>

        <div class = "main">

            <div class ="sidebar1"> </div>  
            <div class ="sidebar2"> </div>          

            <div class = "turinys" >    
             <p id = 'index_greeting_font'> <img src = "a" id = "index_greeting_nuotrauka" ></img>       
             Sveiki atvykę į pasaulinių karų puslapį!
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
          <script src="js/sidebar_scriptai/sidebar_script_normal_page.js"></script> // Script doesnt load
        </body>
    <html>
```

Example of sidebar1.html to which i try to apply script

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>

   <meta charset='utf-8'> 
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Pasauliniai karai</title>

   </head>

<body>

        <p id = "raud_spalva" >
        <div id = "div_atsitikt_skaic">
        <font id = "raud_spalva"> Atsitiktinis skaičius: </font>
        <p id ="rand_faktas_skaicius"> </p>
        <p id = "rand_faktas_skaicius_aprasymas"></p> 
        </div>
        </p>

        <p id = "sidebar_nauja_rubrika"><br><font id ="raud_spalva">  </font> <br> <br>
                <iframe src="" width="180" height="180" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </p>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Is there an error or what ? Here is documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You really shouldn't be loading another entire document into your parent document with ajax.  You should really only load in fragments.  Other than that, it looks like you have your script at the bottom of your page and your logic at the top is in a doc ready.  So depending on how you have your logic in your script include, it's possible it is executing before the ajax loads your divs.

Comment: @Poria   My script uses "document.getElementById("datasss").innerHTML = text; " and by the documentation jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML  . Is it possible conflict?

Comment: @Taplar tried replacing , same.

Comment: What is error in console when you use load ?

Comment: then i dont get it why jquery load is blocking my script

Comment: Can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Poria https://jsfiddle.net/qb120Lcr/

Comment: anyone knows where the problem may be?

Comment: Where is the script which is not working, because i dont see any script in sidebar1.html ?

Comment: @Poria script is in the first file <script src="js/sidebar_scriptai/sidebar_script_normal_page.js"></script> because no way script in sidebar1.html will load because of jquery load

Comment: What is the content ? Did you try put it into sidebar.html ?

Comment: Your script will work if it is loaded after the html it need to work on

Comment: @Poria well its indeed loaded after the html , you can tell it just by lookint at the code.

Comment: @Poria and yes i tried putting script in sidebar.html

Comment: try using getScript to load your js after html loads

Comment: @Poria tried , that doesnt work either

Comment: @Poria anything more to offer?

Comment: Figured it out , just need to call    $.get( "index.html",atnaujinti_laika); to call for function when index is loaded.

Comment: Post the answer here, so that others can also be helped !

Comment: <script src="js/sidebar_scriptai/sidebar_script_index.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script> Loading script from which i will take a function, need to load it first so the html knows that function exists 
  $(document).ready(function(){     // Loading here
    $("#cssmenu").load("meniu.html");
    $(".sidebar1").load("sidebar1.html");
    $(".sidebar2").load("sidebar2.html");
       
    $.get( "index.html",atnaujinti_laika);
                 // After index.html load , execute random_index .. function

 </script> // do this after doc load

Comment: @Poria thanks for the help